# Распарсить таблицу на PHP

Tags: php, массивы, парсер

Задача такая. Мне необходимо разбить получаемую строкой таблицу по tr и внутри tr по td.
На данный момент у меня есть следующее:

```
$doc = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($page);
$table = pq($doc)->find('table > tr > td');
$exp = explode('<td>', pq($table));
```

При print_r($exp) выводится следующее:

```
Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => jake</td>     
[2] => two</td>   
[3] => three</td> 
[4] => 4</td>
[5] => jakes</td>  
[6] => 6</td>
[7] => seven</td> 
[8] => 8</td>
        </tr>)
```

А мне бы хотелось, чтобы результат был таким:

```
Array(
[0] =>array(
    [0] => jake
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => 4
)
[1] => array(
    [0] => jakes
    [1] => 6
    [2] => seven
    [3] => 8
)
```

То есть нужен массив строк tr, где элементами этого массива являются td.
Для дальнейшего помещения этой таблицы сюда:
https://github.com/viossat/arraytotexttable

И не понятно еще, почему он в первый элемент ничего не заносит

Надеюсь, я правильно в правильном направлении вообще =)

Comment: ну так выберите сначала td а потом tr последовательно.